# How sensitive are probability distributions to noise?

Tags: st.statistics, norms, expectation

I'm trying to prove a result but I'm stuck at the very end of it: I'm having troubles understanding how noise propagates when considering a probability distribution. In other words, if I inject some noise in a vector, how does it change its probability distribution? Let's give some notation:

Let $\sigma: \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow (0,1)^d$ be the softmax operator which maps $x$ to the manifold of the probability distributions on $d$ variables defined in the following way:
$$\sigma(x)_i  = \frac{e^{x_i}}{\sum_j e^{x_j}}$$
I have a vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ with norm one. I also have random noise vector $\eta \in \mathbb{R}^d$ with norm $1/k$ taken uniformely at random from the sphere $S^{d-1}$ of radius 1/k, where k is a large natural number.

I need to compute an upper bound of the following expected value, which is the norm of the difference between the vector without noise and the one with injected noise $\eta$:

$$ \mathbb{E}[||\sigma(x) - \sigma(x+\eta)||]$$

I gave a bounty to this question because I really need to understand this problem (I will have to solve several problems of this kind).

Thank you very much!

Comment: In 2 dimensions this can be calculated numerically and visualized, e.g. as below with $x=(2,3)$, $k=10$, $E=0.025$. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=NIntegrate%5BNorm%5B%7Be%5E2,e%5E3%7D%2F(e%5E2%2Be%5E3)-%7Be%5E(2%2BCos%5B2Pi+t%5D%2F10),e%5E(3%2BSin%5B2Pi+t%5D%2F10)%7D%2F(e%5E(2%2BCos%5B2Pi+t%5D%2F10)%2Be%5E(3%2BSin%5B2Pi+t%5D%2F10))%5D,%7Bt,0,1%7D%5D If $f(\eta)$ is the norm, then $f=0$ when $\eta$ is proportional to $(1,1)$ or to $(-1,-1)$. So $f$ can be approximated by two parabolas, and $E[f]\simeq (1/3)(f((1,-1)/k\sqrt{2})+f((-1,1)/k\sqrt{2}))$. In the example, that gives $0.026$.

Comment: Thank you! do you know a way to show the same thing in more dimensions? I'm trying to get an answer but I have no idea how to keep going. Thanks again!

Comment: My next step would be numerical experimentation.

Comment: There is one thing I don't understand from your example: $x = (2,3)$ doesn't have norm one. Did you take care of it in the Wolfram alpha experimentation?
Thanks again

Comment: You can see what I did in WolframAlpha and redo it with $x=(0.6,0.8)$ if you like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\mathbb{E}(|\sigma(x+\eta)-\sigma(x)|)=\mathbb{E}(|J_\sigma\eta|)+O(|\eta|^2)$$where $J_\sigma$ is the Jacobi matrix $$ (J_\sigma)_{i,j}=\frac{e^{x_i}}{\sum_k e^{x_k}}\delta_{i,j} - \frac{e^{x_i+x_j}}{(\sum_k e^{x_k})^2}$$ and $$\mathbb{E}(|J_\sigma\eta|)^2\leq \mathbb{E}(|J_\sigma\eta|^2)=\mathbb{E}(\langle \eta J_\sigma^2\eta\rangle)=\frac{|\eta|^2}{d}\text{Tr}(J_\sigma^2)$$with $$\text{Tr}(J_\sigma^2 )=\sum_i \frac{e^{2x_i}}{(\sum_k e^{x_k})^2}+\sum_{i,j} \frac{e^{2x_i}e^{2x_j}}{(\sum_k e^{x_k})^4} -2\sum_{i}\frac{e^{3x_i}}{(\sum_k e^{x_k})^3} \\ = \sum_i (\sigma(x)_i)^2+\big(\sum_i (\sigma(x)_i)^2\big)^2-2\sum_i (\sigma(x)_i)^3$$

Conclusion : $$\mathbb{E}(|\sigma(x+\eta)-\sigma(x)|)\leq \frac{\eta}{\sqrt{d}}\sqrt{\sum_i (\sigma(x)_i)^2+\big(\sum_i (\sigma(x)_i)^2\big)^2-2\sum_i (\sigma(x)_i)^3
}+O(|\eta|^2)$$

Comment: In the first example above, the $\sigma$ coordinates are $0.27$ and $0.73$, so this gives $\frac{1}{10\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{.61 + .37 - 2(.41)} + O(1/100) \simeq .028$

Comment: Thank you to the both of you!